# MySQLi prepared query failing after first query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have one function selecting a load of information from one table. This then launches another function to get some info from another table.

Here's the shortened code:

```
$con = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$con->select_db("stories_test");

getStories($con);

function getStories($con) {
    ... //get's a load of data from one table
    $result = getStoryName($con, $stringstoryid);
    ... //More stuff here
}

function getStoryName($con) {
    $newquery = "SELECT storyname, genre FROM stories WHERE storyid = 'Anewstory9856'";
    if ($stmt = $con->prepare($newquery)) {
        echo $newquery;
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($storname, $genre);
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            $resultarray = array (
                'storname' => $storname,
                'genre' => $genre
            );
        }
    }
    else {
        echo 'statement failed';
    }
    return $resultarray;
}
```

All I ever get is 'statement failed' from the second query.
I have tried the exact same query in a separate script on its own and it works fine, but here it seems to fail at 'prepare'.

Does anyone have any clues?

Comment: Look for an API function for getting the last error. There is probably more information buried in there that will make it obvious.

Comment: What does `echo $con->error` tell you?  It holds the _real_ error message.

Comment: `$stmt->close();`. Your statement probably has a few things left in it.

Comment: Yes, in the `getStories()` function you say _"gets a load of data from one table"_ If you have not fetched all rows from it, you may have to close an open statement.

Comment: That sounds sensible, I will test, though my laptop has just run out of battery. brb